# Could not load type 'CardInventory.Master' .Net error

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can anyone help me with this error i am getting? 
Could not load type 'CardInventory.Global'.
I have been strungeling all day with this and still have not found a solution.

I have tried to clear my bin and obj and than re add the .dll files. I have also removed and added again the global.asax file but still getting the same error every time i try to run the project

If someone has any idea please share.

Comment: You could start by [edit]ing your question and including the exact exception message and a [mcve]

Comment: There is no exception, i am saying i cant even run neither debug the project. <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="CardInventory.Master" Language="C#" %> this is the row which i giving the error as the browser says when i try to localy run the projecct

Comment: Well, then please post a [mcve]